# Spring Security OAuth 2 without client registration

Tags: spring, oauth

In OAuth 2 client_id is a required parameter, and if I understand correctly, I need to register the client somehow (by admin, or client register himself by registration service etc.).

But what if I want to do it without client registration on server? Can I use one client_id to identity type of client instead of registration every client with unique client_id on server?

For example client_id=android_app, and there will be many clients with such client_id, and as well will be others, with other types. ( The authorities will be validated by native users roles. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make multiple client applications share one client_id. It's up to you. However, note that all of such client applications are recognized as the same single client application from a viewpoint of the authorization server. If client_id is shared, the authorization page returned from the authorization server will show the same single application name to end-users even if client applications are different. If it's okay, share one client_id among all of your client applications.

Comment: Thanks for request. I think it's okay, in my case Resource server and Authorization server is the same stateless backend application.